# Maintaining Bluetooth connection in background in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background, bluetooth

At the moment, I'm searching and connecting to Bluetooth via a class that extends AppCompatActivity (it's an activity).

The problem I have is that I want the user to bring up a Dialog, where they can search for their Bluetooth device and connect to the appropriate one. After the user has connected, I obviously want the Bluetooth connection to be maintained and running in the background.

I tried to do this in a Service and Thread, however I'm unable to use Activity classes in Service and Thread. So I'm basically unsure on how to go about this.

Any help please? Thanks. I can provide code if you want me to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `Service`, now you will need to have a `service` connection to call `service's` methods from `activity`.
Also you may need to communicate to `activity` from `Service`, hence use `BroadcastReceiver` or `Handlers` for the purpose.

Comment: Hi there, I'm a beginner with Android. Could you please elaborate a bit more on your answer, I'm really confused. Thanks.

Comment: Read 1. how to implement Service. 2. How to get Service connection 3. Communication between service and Activity

Comment: Good answer!  @BadProgrammer: There are numerous ways to communicate with services, depending what you want to achieve. One way is to use AIDL. You will find extensive information on services in the official Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Besides Google, there's the book "Efficient Android Threading" from Goransson that might be a good introduction into the general topic.

Comment: @Newtron that is a reference of point 2.To get Service connection :)